# C++, Same code won't work btw CLion & Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clion

I have the following code in VS:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inData;
    int temp;

    inData.open("test_file.txt");

    do {
        inData >> temp;
        cout << temp << " ";
    } while (!(inData.eof()));

    inData.close();


    return 0;
}
```

test_file.txt contains the following data (it's a single line):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 10 11
```

When I built and ran this in VS, it worked fine. Today, when I tried to run it on CLion, it gives me garbage data. I tried creating a new project from scratch in CLion and copy-pasting just the code in main.cpp, but still gives me random data. And now I'm wasting my Saturday wrestling with my IDE instead of just finishing my homework. Any help?

Comment: First of all, are you sure that the program manages to open the file? And while your loop might be marginally better than `while (!infile.eof())` [using `eof()` in a loop condition should always be considered wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons).

Comment: Maybe the file is not even found. Your code does not care if the file was opened or not.

Comment: Thanks. I just figured out what the problem is, CLion doesn't recognize the path, VS does.

Comment: The problem is very likely that the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) differs between the two environments, meaning the relative path to the file is different. Consider to *always* set the working directory in the project run settings.

Comment: You should put some error handling in your code.

Comment: Will do. My project is much bigger than this, but I was just testing the very beginning: TDD.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue is. CLion doesn't recognize the parameter as a path, whereas VS does.

Comment: IDEs are not compilers. CLion is not the issue. It's the compiler that it uses that interprets your code differently: most likely gcc or clang.  Where as Visual Studio ships the Microsoft compiler.  And when you say, "doesn't recognize the path", that leads me to believe it's really a Linux vs Windows issue.